# Why does my op-amp swing randomly when the inputs are disconnected?

Tags: operational-amplifier

In Electronics class today we were using a TL081 op-amp. When I disconnected the inverting and noninverting inputs, the op-amp's output (driving an LED) started switching on and off rapidly. What causes these weird oscillations?

Comment: If you could see the LED flashing, then it wasn't switching on and off 'rapidly' ;-)

Comment: @Will Dean Got a scope ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Op-amps are very high gain differential amplifiers, with high input impedance. A few millivolts difference between the disconnected inputs can be enough to drive the output to one rail or the other. So chances are your amp is picking up noise enough from the environment to drive it one way and another.

Answer (score 3):

The TL081 has a FET input stage, whereas many older opamps have a BJT input stage. This makes a great difference for the input bias current. While the input bias current for the LM741 may look low at typically 80nA, for the TL081 this is 5pA! (Analog's [AD549](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD549.pdf) does even 2 orders of magnitude better with 60fA, that's about 1 electron every 3\$\mu\$s).
The higher the input impedance of the opamp the easier the inputs will work as antennas an pick up from the ever present electric fields in the air, and cause a voltage at the output. With the LM741 for instance this will be hardly a problem.

Comment: Holy cats! That is a minute signal...I'd have nightmares about shielding if I had to design a circuit using that baby.